# Como identificar o botão que foi clicado?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho vários botões e eu gostaria de comparar o texto do botão clicado com uma variável do tipo `String`.

Isso sem usar isso:

```
if (evento.getSource() == botaoXl) {
    // Fazer isto...
} else if (evento.getSource() == botaoY) {
    // Fazer aquilo...
}
```

Comment: Por que você quer checar pela string? O texto dos botões será dinâmico? Você pode adicionar uma escuta aos botões e realizar tal comportamento. Você está usando qual GUI?

Comment: `setActionCommand` e `getActionCommand` estão aí pra isso.

Comment: Coloquei a tag swing na sua pergunta porque isso daí me parece ser swing. Se não for, então solicito que edite a pergunta especificando exatamente qual é a tecnologia ou framework que você está usando.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal usar `((JButton) evento.getSource()).getText()`?

Comment: Eu acho que nem precisa do evento.getSource(). Somente o botao.getText(), desde que o botão já tenha sido renderizado, já retorna o texto do botao.

Comment: @diegofm Isso supondo que dentro do `ActionListener` haja alguma referência à variável do botão que faz isso. Na minha concepção, em um projeto bem feito, o botão em questão dentro do `ActionListener` seria tão óbvio que essa questão tornar-se-ia totalmente desnecessária e trivial. Mas olhando para o código da pergunta, parece que um super-mega-power-`ActionListener` genérico é usado para tudo e daí no código começam a surgir essas gambis. Infelizmente como não temos mais dados sobre o contexto do código, fica difícil sugerir alguma abordagem diferente dentro do *big picture*.